# Запрос на поиск ближайшей записи, по двум параметрам

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, веб-программирование

У меня в MySQL есть таблица `time` со столбцами `min` и `sec` в которых хранятся числа. Пользователь вводит два числа(например min1 и sec1).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на SQL составить запрос, который выбирал бы из таблицы `time` только ту запись у которой `min <= min1` и `sec <= sec1`, при этом эта запись обладает максимальным `min` удовлетворяющим условию(а если таких записей несколько, то нужно выбрать запись с большим `sec` удовлетворяющим условию. )

Т.е. говоря русским языком мне нужно сделать, что бы из таблицы выбиралось максимальное время(`min` и `sec`), которое меньше значения введённого пользователем.

Comment: Есть такая функция в sql - MAX http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `min` <= 'min1' AND `sec` <= 'sec1' ORDER BY `min` DESC, `sec` DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментария от [Равнодушный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/8603/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `time`
WHERE
  `min` <= 'min1' AND
  `sec` <= 'sec1'
ORDER BY
  `min` DESC,
  `sec` DESC
LIMIT 1
```